# ASP.NET MVC - Image + Authenticated Users Only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

is it possible to somehow only allow authenticated users to view certain images? I'm building a web gallery at the moment, and I dont want non-authenticated users to be able to see the images.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could put those images somewhere on the server where users don't have access (like for example the `~/App_Data` folder) in order to prevent direct access to them and then use a controller action to serve them. This action will be decorated with an Authorize attribute to allow only authenticated users to call it:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Image(string name)
{
    var appData = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var image = Path.Combine(appData, name + ".png");
    return File(image, "image/png");
}
```

and then:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Image", "SomeController", new { name = "foo" })" alt="" />
```

Inside the view you could also test whether the user is authenticated before displaying the image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to hide images from unauthenticated users.

Depending on how your images are being displayed, you might hide them through

1.using the `Authorize` attribute on the controller action

2.wrapping the HTML in the view that will display the images in

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
    // image HTML here   
}
```

You'll want to put the images somewhere where they cannot be viewed without being authenticated, such as in `App_Data` as Darin suggests.