# Missing Image Default

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, configuration

Is there a way (perhaps IIS, web.config, or other) where I can set a default image for missing images on a website?  I'd like to send a custom image in the case where the image you are trying to view doesn't exist.

I'm using MVC3, and I know that I can create a custom Image controller action like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5606575/435460.  I'd like a more general solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an HTTPModule to intercept requests for common image extensions, test for the presence of the file, and if missing instead return a default image.

Find an overview for writing an HTTPModule [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/HttpModuleandHttpHandle.aspx)

You might also consider a look at this [Codeplex project](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/16449)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an HTTP Handler would be of use here?

Have a look at this article for creative use of HTTPHandlers to prevent file leaching. Pretty sure it could be ammended to serve a default image when it 404's.

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-291916.html